# Is it bad to mix different refrigerants?

Tags: ac, r134a, r12

I'm mainly wondering about different brands of refrigerants. In other words, mixing one brand of R134a with another brand, not mixing R12 and R134a (or anything like that).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no difference between brands of R134A, unless there is some additive in it which will be stated on the label.

Some include leak sealer, never use this, ever.

[The only real difference is Price.](http://refrigeranthq.com/brand-important/)

Comment: What's bad about brands with leak sealer?

Comment: They can clog expansion tubes and other critical internal parts of the AC, never use mechanic in a can products.